# Change the code so that the name of the file you will write, will be entered from command line

Tags: c++, c

I've changed the code. And I do the following:

1. Open Terminal
2. Write gcc program.c -o program1
3. ./program1
4. I get Error!

I conclude that no file is being created, the pointer `fptr==0` and that is why I get that error. Also when I enter more strings or integers after ./program1 (like ./program 1 2) shows "Error!" again. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int n;
  FILE *fptr;
  fptr=fopen(argv[0],"w");
  if(fptr==NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
  }
  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  fprintf(fptr,"%d",n);
  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: neither the title of your question nor the text in it make any sense - except for your algorithm i guess. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This instruction tries to open the executable of your programme in write mode:

```
fptr=fopen(argv[0],"w");   // 0 is the programme name
```

This fails certainly because of administrative priviledges that are (fortunately) missing.

You may add a more usefull error message using [`perror()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/?kw=perror)

If you want to write data in a file provided on the command line,  you should consider:

```
if (argc<=1) {
    printf ("Missing command line argument !\n"); 
    exit(1); 
}
fptr=fopen(argv[1],"w");   // first argument is in 1
...
```

and calling your programme from the command line:

```
./program1 myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`argv[0]` is the name of the program, if you pass the file path, you should use `argv[1]`

Try to launch like:

```
$ ./program mypath/file.name
```

`argv[0]` is program, `argv[1]` is mypatch/file.name